# How to print the value (string) of an elmentFinder when an error occurs in protractor

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I have following code -

```
    export async function waitTillClickable(e: ElementFinder): Promise<ElementFinder> {
        const conditions = EC.visibilityOf(e);
        await browser.wait(conditions, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, `Element did not return within ${DEFAULT_TIMEOUT / 1000} seconds: ${e}`);
        return e;
    }
```

Now the problem is that when it times out or doesn't find the elment, it says -

```
Element did not return within 10 seconds: [Object][Object]
```

I need that instead of [Object][Object], I could see what locator did it fail for, something like `by.xpath('//...')`. Tried using JSON.stringify on `{e}` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `element.locator().toString()` to get the locator of a webelement.

```
 export async function waitTillClickable(e: ElementFinder): Promise<ElementFinder> {
        const conditions = EC.visibilityOf(e);
        await browser.wait(conditions, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, `Element did not return within ${DEFAULT_TIMEOUT / 1000} seconds: ${e.locator()}`);
        return e;
    }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Its not working. e.locator().toSting() is not a function error.

Comment: But removing toString works. Accepting it as the answer. Thanks much.